# used a bottle to fill with water

Tags: infinitives, past-participles

Are "to fill" and "filled" both okay in the following?
What's the difference in meaning?

> He used a bottle **filled** / **to fill** with water.

Answer (score 1):

"*He used a bottle filled with water*" - He used a bottle that had water in it to do something.

"*He used a bottle to fill with water*" - Is incorrect and doesn't mean anything.

"*He used a bottle to fill **the bowl** with water*" - He filled the bowl with water by using a bottle

Comment: Is "he bought a bottle to fill with water" correct?

Comment: Yes. It means he got an empty bottle with the intention of filling it with water.

Comment: Could you explain why a mere replacement of "used" with "bought" should make the sentence acceptable?

Comment: When using "*used*" the whole construct is "*used something **to** do something*". The "*to*" applies to the verb. "*To fill with water*" is missing an object and is not sufficient as a description of an activity. 

When using "*bought*", "*brought*", "*made*" etc. the construct is "*bought something*" and the "*to*" is now a used to describe the bottle. In this case the intention of filling it.

Comment: If the object of the exercise was to end up with a bottle of water, we would simply say "He filled a bottle with water" - there is no need for the verb _use_.